# Calculating regional contribution to national GDP growth

Tags: statistics, share, economics

Is there a simple way in R or Stata to calculate the regional contribution to national GDP growth?

For instance if I have the following, how do I calculate the contribution of the regions' growth to the overall national growth?

| Region/country | % change | weight |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Region 1 | 0.3 | 0.25 |
| Region 2 | 0.1 | 0.25 |
| Region 3 | 0.25 | 0.25 |
| Region 4 | 0.15 | 0.25 |
| Country | 0.2 | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

To get the contribution of each region, you just need to multiply the %change by it"s weight